# React Native - How to load local image using the uri in Image Component?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, image, react-native

**I know we can load the local image with:**

```
<Image source={require('folder/image.png')}/>
```

**But i need to load the image like this:**

```
<Image source={{uri: 'folder/image.png'}}/>
```

It works for network images but it doesn't work for local images and even it does not give any error for local images and silently does not display the image. Can anyone tell how to load the local image using the `uri` property?

Answer (score 11):

In case you are using Expo to build your React Native application, this might help:

1) Install expo-asset: `expo install expo-asset`

2) Initialize and set your imageUri:

```
import {Asset} from 'expo-asset';

const imageURI = Asset.fromModule(require('../../assets/test.png')).uri;
```

3) In my case, I needed it on a Thumbnail from NativeBase:

```
<Thumbnail square source={{uri: imageURI}}/>
```

Docs: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/asset/

Comment: This still need to use `require`, is this any better than put all `require` method into a js Object? eg. `export default { image: require('./image.jpg') }`

Comment: @Colo Ghidini thanks this helped find a solution also

Answer (score 9):

These are the three ways to render images in react-native , 
In your case you can encode the image

- you can `require` image

  `source={require('/react-native/img/favicon.png')}`
- you can get image from web

  `source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}`
- or you can encode the image

  `source={{uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='}}`

as doc suggested as below

```
export default class DisplayAnImage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          source={require('/react-native/img/favicon.png')}
        />
        <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}
        />
        <Image
          style={{width: 66, height: 58}}
          source={{uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

or you can create a json file that contains the encoded string of the image 
image.json

```
{imageString: '64encodedString'}
```

them import the file

```
import image from 'image.json';
```

then image

```
<Image source:{{uri:image.imageString}} />
```

Comment: so, you mean it is not possible for local images to be loaded with `uri`?

Comment: it is possible to load local images using {{url:'asset:local_file'}}

Comment: I tried require, it does not wotk.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in AndroidManifest file.

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" <=== here
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```