# Importing photos utilising URI in REACT NATIVE

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello and thanks for your time!

So since there're a couple of similiar questions out there, I'll make this quick:

I've got some LOCAL images/photos loaded dynamically from an object, something "require" won't let me do.

I've already tried what's been discussed on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/751) way back in 2015, doesn't seem to do the trick for me.

**Is it really (still?) considered best practice to import these images/photos as an encoded string via JSON as already suggested [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779164/react-native-how-to-load-local-image-using-the-uri-in-image-component) ?**

...or am I missing something?

(Look, I'm really sorry for reopening this discussion once again, but maybe someone could mark this as a "*Best-Practice for utilizing local images in a non-static way*") - it would then also be very helpful for other programmers who haven't really wrapped their head around React (Native) that much yet.)

Thanks for your input!